# tensorflow won't release system memory after force quit

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I use `tf.train.string_input_producer()` and `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` to read data.

Since I don't have a good stop criterion, I manually terminate the training program by `Ctrl-C`.

I find that every time I terminated the program in this way, there were a huge amount of memory not released (checking by "free -g" command).

And when I used `top` command, there were no programs using those memory.
I have to reboot my machine after some numbers of training to release those memory.

Is it because I didn't explicitly close those queues? I think those memory should store my input data, otherwise it won't be so huge (50GB).

Thanks.

Comment: `free -g` undercounts free memory (ie, some memory is held by various buffers, but it will get released as soon as it's needed)